# Two LAN cables when using Remote Access Card?

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, linux-networking, remote-access, ethernet

I recently bought a HP MicroServer N54L and a HP Remote Access Card.
Connecting to the server over a KVM viewer for BIOS setup etc. works fine, but when it comes to installing Ubuntu 14.04. the automatic network authentication fails, telling me:

`Your network is probably not using the DHCP protocoll. Alternatively, the DHCP server may be slow or some network hardware is not working properly" (it offers to retry or retry with specific DHCP).`

The RAC uses DHCP, as it got its IP address automatically.

**Now my questions are:**

1. Do I also have to plug in the onboard network card or can I use the RAC as my only network adapter?
2. Why is Ubuntu not able to autodetect? Is this correct and I need to manually configure it (if so how?) or is there a simple mistake I might have done?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The iLO RAC is a completely separate NIC. If you want the OS to have a network connection you must also connect the on-board NIC to the network.
2. I'm guessing you don't have the NIC plugged in, and Ubuntu has no magical powers to make a network connection out of an unplugged NIC.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was hoping to be able to use the RAC also as a NIC (instead of the onboard NIC). Or is it standard to always use both (and therefore two cables)?

Comment: In Proliant 3xx, 5xx, 7xx, 9xx, and select 1xx models the onboard NIC can be shared with iLO. But that is not the case with the 5x servers.

Comment: @Webx10 A RAC is not only a separate NIC it's a completely different "machine". It may be attached to the server but it is only there for managing the actual machine like you would do if you had physical access. Its purpose is to have the same possibilities you would have with physical access to your server (like doing a hard reset, forced shutdown, plug in a monitor and see BIOS output etc.).

Comment: @ChrisS Thanks! So two cables it is I guess. Or is there any way around it?

Comment: @Broco Thats exactly why I bought it and it is working great. I was just hoping to also use it as the main (and only) NIC

Comment: @Webx10 I suppose you could connect both to a small switch and then back to the network from there... Otherwise, no, you have to connect both NICs somehow.

Comment: @ChrisS : Thanks again! I've marked it as solved. Next time I'll check again for a differen ProLiant model...